# How to skip or ignore the column without using Select NULL?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

***I have to declare that i ask the question before ,but i find some wording mistakes that cause misleading  .Hence , i decide to delete the old question and ask the question again.***

Here is my sql:

```
Select officer , NULL ,NULL, salary from table
```

As i use ADO to run sql in excel , second and third column are needed to input data before running the sql query.

But i use NULL to skip 2 column .The sql query would clear and reset my data  or excel formula stored in column 2 and 3,because i choose to NULL these 2 columns .

Hence , how to skip these two columns without affecting these two column data or formula ?

Visualization :

- > officer , Column 2,Column 3, salary
- > **_ ,  2,=sum(B2*C2), _**

SQL query run :    `Select officer , NULL ,NULL, salary from table`

- > officer , Column 2(NULL),Column 3(NULL), salary
- > **988, ___ ,___   , $4789**// the SQL query clears the original data stored  in column 2 ,3

(___  means blank)

How to solve this problem?

Comment: why don't you run two queries like `Select officer from table ORDER BY xxx` and `Select salary from table ORDER BY xxx` where ORDER seems to be required to be sure you get matching set of data

Comment: the other way is to load data to excel by looping through Recordset, not by `.CopyFromRecordset`. Loop would then go only for 1st, fourth and fifth fields...

Comment: @ KazimierzJawor  now i already built one sql statement `mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn sheet6.Range("A5").CopyFromRecordset mrs` But this sql statement across the cells where no need to be placed

Comment: @ KazimierzJawor you mean placing the data to cell in every field ?How is the syntax like, not by .CopyFromRecordset?

Comment: I suggested two SQLs instead of one...!  see sample below by @daZza

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are currently inserting the queried data directly to your worksheet?

If that's so, I suggest using a recordset to hold the results of your query. Then loop through it. This way you can decide in which cells you want to put the data.

A starting point could be this (modify according to your needs):

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
 .Provider = "YOUR.PROVIDER"
  .ConnectionString = "YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING"
.Open
End With
strQuery = "SELECT officer, salary FROM table"
Set rs = cn.Execute(strQuery)
Do While Not rs.EOF
  For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count

    ' Insert data to your worksheet here
    ' rs.Fields(0).Value holds the value for officer
    ' rs.Fields(1).Value holds the value for salary

  Next
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
```